# How can I pass this string through thymeleaf th:replace?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, knockout.js, thymeleaf

Originally my index.html looked like this:

```
<div data-bind="attr: {id: 'newsEntry_'+ $parentContext.$index() +'_lead_' + $index() + '_toolbar'}">
                    ...
</div>
```

which works!

I separated that part to an external edit.html file and includet it with thymeleafs th:replace to my index.html:

```
<div th:replace="fragments/editor :: editor(binding='data-bind=\'attr: {id: \'newsEntry_\'+ $parentContext.$index() +\'_lead_\' + $index() + \'_toolbar\'}\'')" >...</div>
```

fragments/editor.html:

```
<div th:fragment="editor(binding)">
    <div th:attr="${binding}">...</div>
</div>
```

I get this error:

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse
>   as assignation sequence: "${binding}" (fragments/editor:9)

data-bind is the binding from knockout.js.

I think the error is something with the escpaing of " ' \'

Answer (score 1):

I got it:

index.html:

```
<div th:replace="fragments/editor :: editor(binding='attr:{ id: \'newsEntry_\'+ $parentContext.$index() +\'_lead_\' + $index() + \'_toolbar\'}')" >...</div>
```

editor.html:

```
<div th:fragment="editor(binding)">
    <div th:attr="data-bind=${binding}"></div>
</div>
```